Disc robot with ball caster wheels
I want to build a robot shaped like a disc(cylinder) with a diameter of 11 centimeters, a height of 8 centimeters, and a weight of approximately 500 grams. The goal is for it to glide(slip) freely and smoothly for at least 1 meter on a flat surface (such as glass) when gently pushed. I used 6 ball caster wheels underneath the cylinder, but it doesn’t perform as well as I’d like and doesn’t glide smoothly enough. What method can I use to improve this?
